# How -Dlogging.level JVM argument is handled in spring boot, spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, apache-commons-config

I have a spring cloud application, which under the covers uses spring boot.

In the bootstrap phase of the app I am using some classes from the apache commons config library under: `org.apache.commons.configuration`

My application is started with this flag per the spring docs:

`-Dlogging.level.org.apache.commons.configuration=INFO`

Despite this, i am still getting DEBUG level logs emitted during the bootstrap phase of spring....

I am lost as to how to properly specify the log level of INFO specified for the bootstrap phase of spring boot.

Comment: What does the rest of your logging configuration look like? Also, what are you using to log (i.e. log4j2, logback, etc.)?

Comment: Whatever comes w/ spring-boot, spring-cloud, slf4j w/ logback

Comment: But how come you're seeing any DEBUG level messages at all? Did you set the root logging level to DEBUG?

Comment: set root logger is DEBUG, and `-Dlogging.level.org.apache.commons.configuration=INFO`

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you are not setting debug=true in application properties or not passing --debug flag to the application.

In application.properties set:

```
debug=false
```

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of spring boot has a specific order, so probably somewhere in the application or bootstrap configuration files the logging level is configured to DEBUG.
Source:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I understand, however this system level property to the JVM is `-Dlogging.level.org.apache.commons.configuration=INFO` yet that is eminating DEBUG logs